# different variable Assignment in python

Tags: python

While having a look at some deep-learning code in Python, I came across some below lines of code. I am not sure what it does. I have never saw such assignments in python untill now. Can someone help me understand it?

```
top_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```

What does the above line of code do? Why the 2 `()` concatenated? It is very similar to object casting in Java. What are such assignments called in Python?

Comment: This is not specifically a special *assignment*. It is just a "special" *expression* used in assignment. Using `()` is to call stuff. This means that `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` in itself returns something that is callable, which gets called with the `x` argument

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the same thing as

```
gap2d = GlobalAveragePooling2D()
top_model = gap2d(x)
```

(though without the extra variable).

What it does depends on the framework you're using.

Answer (score 2):

`GlobalAveragePooling2D` is a class.

`GlobalAveragePooling2D()` creates an instance of that class.

This class happens to be callable (i.e. has a `__call__` method defined). So it can behave like a function.

`GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)` calls this newly created object with x as an argument.

The result of this call is then assigned (just a normal assignment) to `top_model`